# using strtok function to tokenize a sentence

Tags: c++, token, tokenize, strtok

I am having a little trouble using the strtok() function. What I am trying to do is grab a sentence from a keyboard, then create tokens for every space in the sentence, and then finally print every word that is separated by a space . My current output is blank I have a feeling is something to do with me delimiter but im am not to sure, any feedback would be great thank you !

Example of input from keyboard:

```
The sky is really cool
```

Example of Output:

```
the
sky 
is
really 
cool
```

My code so far

```
   #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
   #include<iostream>
   #include<string>
   using namespace std;

 int main(){
 char sent[99];
 int length = strlen(sent);

 cout << "Enter a Sentence" << endl;
 cin.getline(sent,99);
 char* tok = strtok(sent," ");
 int i = 0;

while (i<=length)
{
    tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    cout << tok;
    i++;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Output so far

```
Enter a Sentence
the sky is really cool

                            Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: tok = (NULL, " "); ???

Comment: Another way to do it is to use getchar and keep appending it to a string until space is read (or a newline).  Then there is no need to use strtok which is horrible.

Comment: `tok = (NULL, " ")` ==> `tok = strtok(NULL, " ");`, but that will eventually open a whole new can of worms with the algorithm you're using, which is wrong. `length` is calculated from an uninitialized `sent` char buffer, so doing anything with that is outright undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues that need to be fixed in your code:

1. The logic you are using in the `while` loop is incorrect.
2. You are going to miss printing the first token.

Here's a simplified `main`:

```
int main(){
   char sent[99];

   cout << "Enter a Sentence" << endl;
   cin.getline(sent,99);
   char* tok = strtok(sent," ");
   while (tok != NULL) // Correct logic to use to stop looping.
   {
      cout << tok << endl;  // Print the current token before getting the next token.
      tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `length` at all, since `strtok()` will return a null pointer if it doesn't find any more delimeters:

```
char* token = strtok(sent," ");
while (token != NULL) {
    std::cout << token << '\n';
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Since this is tagged C++, you could also use `istringstream` with a `std::string`:

```
std::istreamstream is(sent);
std::string word;
while (is >> word) {
    std::cout << word << '\n';
}
```